# Javascript заменить знаки

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mask

Есть функция и она работает.

```
function mask() {
    this.sum = this.sum.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
    if (isNaN(this.sum))
        this.sum = "0";
    sign = (this.sum == (this.sum = Math.abs(this.sum)));
    this.sum = Math.floor(this.sum * 100 + 0.50000000001);
    cents = this.sum % 100;
    this.sum = Math.floor(this.sum / 100).toString();
    if (cents < 10)
        cents = "0" + cents;
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((this.sum.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
        this.sum = this.sum.substring(0, this.sum.length - (4 * i + 2)) + ',' +
        this.sum.substring(this.sum.length - (4 * i + 2));
```

На выходе получаю:

```
51,000,00
```

Не могу разобраться, как заменить первую запятую на точку.

Comment: А где вы используете аргумент функции? (sum)

Comment: sum это поля в vue компоненте изначально он sum: ' ';

Comment: Так а зачем оно аргуметом? this.sum это не sum, и у вас там в родительский скоп чето утекает..

Comment: убрал аргумент, да я его не использую.

Comment: функция по сути слушает что вводится в input  и форматирует вывод (вывод связан v-model="sum")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего использовать [Number.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
let model = {
  sum: '$3,599.99',
  format() {
    let num = +this.sum.replace(/[$,]/g, '');
    return Number(num.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString()
  }
};

console.log(model.format());
```

В русской локализации разделитель тысяч не точка, а пробел. Если вам всё таки нужны точки, замените на них пробелы, либо используйте другую локаль.
Например, немецкую:

```js
let model = {
  sum: '$3,599.99',
  format() {
    let num = +this.sum.replace(/[$,]/g, '');
    return Number(num.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('de-DE')
  }
};

console.log(model.format());
```

Comment: проверку на isNaN исключил только для простоты, добавите сами..

Comment: sum я получаю, когда пользователь вводит данные, конечный sum некогда не известен.

Тут нужно именно при вводе  в Input вставить первый пробел или точку, а потом запятую.

Функция не должна возвращать значения, а лишь задавать текущий this.sum

Comment: нужно нечто вроде sum: this.sum, вместо sum: '$3,599.99',